# Haxe - How to declare variable to be either instance of parent or child class

Tags: inheritance, haxe

Suppose I have two classes:

```
class PlayerManagerParent {
   public function new(){
   }  
}

class GameManagerParent {
   public var playerManager:PlayerManagerParent();

   public function new(){
   }  
}
```

which then I subclass as

```
class PlayerManagerChild extends PlayerManagerParent {
   public function new(){
      super();
   }  

   public function someMethod(){
   }
}

class GameManagerChild extends GameManagerParent {

   public function new(){
      super();
      this.playerManager = new PlayerManagerChild();
   }  
}
```

Then I make instance of `GameManagerChild` and want to access `someMethod()`:

```
var gameManager:GameManagerChild = new GameManagerChild();
gameManager.playerManager.someMethod();
```

which I of course cannot do, as `gameManager.playerManager` is type of `playerManager:PlayerManagerParent` that doesn't define `someMethod()` and compiler / typechecker gives me error.

How can I solve this without declaring `someMethod()` in parent class, or setting `playerManager` type to `Dynamic` (which would be an option, but then I cannot iterate over iterable fields in `playerManager`, for example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a constrained parameterized type for this:

```
class PlayerManagerParent {
   public function new(){
   }  
}

class GameManagerParent<T:PlayerManagerParent> {
   public var playerManager:T;

   public function new(){
   }  
}
```

With this, you can extend like this:

```
class PlayerManagerChild extends PlayerManagerParent {
   public function new(){
      super();
   }  

   public function someMethod(){
   }
}

class GameManagerChild extends GameManagerParent<PlayerManagerChild> {

   public function new(){
      super();
      this.playerManager = new PlayerManagerChild();
   }  
}
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
var child = new GameManagerChild();
child.playerManager.someMethod();
```

**Live example:**
http://try.haxe.org/#21bfC

> **See also:**
>   http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameters.html
>
> Protip: You could even mark it as `@:generic`, which might be gain extra performance at some platforms:
>   http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-generic.html

Comment: Meh, yours is more documented :)

Comment: Well, that partially solves my problem, but when I try to do this in your example Test class: `var child2:GameManagerParent<PlayerManagerParent> = child;`, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's correct, but I think that is also exactly expected, because the Parent does not have this functionality, right?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use type parameters, something like:

```
class GameManagerParent<PM:PlayerManagerParent> {
     public var playerManager : PM;
}

class GameManagerChild 
extends GameManagerParent<PlayerManagerChild> {
     public function new() {
         playerManager = new PlayerManagerChild();
     }
}
```